# find the number of solutions of the equation $a_1x_1+a_2x_2+...+a_nx_n=0$ in a linear space over Galois field

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

Linear space $\Bbb F_p^n$ contains $p^n$ vectors $( x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ with length $n$ over finite $\Bbb F_p$ Galois field comprised from $p$ elements.

How many solutions in $\Bbb F_p^n$ has the equation

$\alpha_1x_1+\alpha_2x_2+...+\alpha_nx_n=0$ ( where not all $\alpha_i \in  \Bbb F_p$ are zeroes) ?

---

*This problem is taken from Kostrikin A., I., "Introduction to linear algebra 2"*.

Comment: Given a specific vector $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$, you mean?

Comment: no, there are p^n vectors of length n in this space. Each element in vector is taken from F_p GF. How many solutions has the equation given?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: the set of solutions forms a vector space over ${\mathbb F}_p$. What is its dimension? What does that tell you about its number of elements?

Comment: Is the dimension of a set of solution equal to ( n - 1)? So there are n - 1 independent solutions, but how many total solutions are there? Is this p ^ ( n - 1) ?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: My confusion was because initially I thought about each x in equation as n-length vector. But this doesn't change anything, the answer in such a case is the same.